# Помогите дописать алгоритм

Tags: c#, алгоритм, олимпиада

Не пойму как получить количество квадратов.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

с#

```
        static long GCD(long a, long b)
        {
            while (b != 0)
            {
                b = a % (a = b);
            }
            return Math.Abs(a);
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            int l = 1680;
            int h = 640;

            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, h, l);

            Console.WriteLine("Сторона крупнейшего квадрату:" + GCD(rect.Height, rect.Width));



            Console.ReadKey();

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(l / "Сторона крупнейшего квадрату") * (h / "Сторона крупнейшего квадрату")
```